# How to replace NaN with null from Mongo shell?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

I have made a `json` file using `pandas` by combining two other `pandas` dataframes. But after uploading it to server and importing it to a new database's new collection using `mongoimport`, I have found that all the blank string fields which should be appeared as `null` are now showing as `NaN`. How can I convert these `NaN`s to `null`s from mongo shell? Please note that I have to do it from the server, and there is no `MongoDBCompass` installed there. I have to do everything from console (`PuTTy`).

Comment: How working if replace `NaN` to `None` in pandas? Like `df = df.mask(df.isna(), None)`

Comment: @jezrael yeah, I saw this fix, and it should work, but if I do so I need to upload the corrected `json` to the server and perform `mongoimport` again. As the `json` is large, it will take crazy length of time to do the whole things again. As, `mongoimport` is slow for large `json`s. Hence, I am looking for a solution to fix it from `mongo shell`.

Comment: Ya, understand it. then no idea ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was just an update operation away. I fixed the problem with the following mongo shell `update` command to replace all `NaN`s with `null`s:

The `{multi: true}` for replacing all of the matches.

```
database_name.collection_name.update({"field_name_having_NaN": {$eq: NaN}}, {$set: {"field_name_having_NaN": null}}, {multi: true});
```

Reference:
[MongoDB Field Update Operator - $set](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/mongodb-field-update-operator-$set.php)